# SQL Server user permission on different schema

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL Azure database and there are already thousands of objects under the DBO schema.

I want to create a new user with specific access requirements

the requirement is below.

1. User can only see a few of the objects under the dbo schema
2. User can make an update/select/alter/execute..etc. any type of modifications, including adding or removing columns from the objects they are allowed to see.
3. User can add new objects under the dbo schema.
4. User should not see the objects(which they are not allowed to see) under the dbo schema in the SSMS browser.

Can you help me to setup the user with specification above?

Comment: because of other reasons, I can not use a different schema.

Comment: This would be possible without #3. `ALTER` permission on the schema is required to create new objects and that confers the ability to see all objects in the schema.

Comment: Hi @arif coskun Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

As  Dan Guzman said this would be possible without #3. Beacuse "Create table" is only a database level permission, cannot be assigned at the schema level.
A user can be defined as the schema owner. If the user has "Create Table" permissions at the database level and is a schema owner, all tables will be created in the schema he/she owns.

1. Create login and user in Azure SQL:

```
use master;
CREATE login user1 with password='SafePassword'

use userDb;
CREATE USER user1 FOR LOGIN user1;  

GO
```

2. We can use following query to generate grant T-SQL script. Select the tables you want to grant to the user.

```sql
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON "' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '"."' + TABLE_NAME + '" TO "user1"' FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: I dont want the user can see the all objects with dbo schema. This is what I can grant only specific objects as the code you shared.  But I want the user can create new table with dbo object. this is not possible with your code.

Comment: I have tried the below code. I wanted to give the user full access on dbo and deny the object which I don't him to modify. That works, but the user can see the objects even though no permission to select or modify them. I want the user does not to see the object which I deny to

CREATE USER limited_access_user WITH PASSWORD = '***'




GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, ALTER, EXECUTE
  ON SCHEMA::dbo TO limited_access_user;
GO



DENY SELECT,INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [dbo].[table] TO [limited_access_user]

Comment: If the user can create new table with dbo object. He will be the  schema owner, so we can't grant the create permission to him.

Comment: Do you mean " we can not create deny permission for him to see the objects?"

Comment: No, I mean the same as  @Dan Guzman said.

Comment: so as far as I understand, there is no way to achieve my goal. If I grant "select access" to the user on dbo schema, he is going to see the list of tables anyway regardless of which deny rules I run.

Comment: Try to delete this user and rebuild it. Is this user assigned other role permissions?  I tried my code and it works well.

Comment: to be honest- I did not understand the solution you provided.